# JQuery add row to table and bind event to last item only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append a copy of a select menu to the bottom of a table when a selection is made in the last select menu in the list. At this point I'd only like to apply the behaviour to the last select menu in the table. The code below adds in the row to the table but fails to unbind the action successfully, and as a result the first select menu continues to show the behaviour, even after the action has been unbound.

Javascript:

```
var selectRow;
$(document).ready(function() {
    selectRow = $('#selectWrapper').html();
    rebindLastSelectBox();  
});

function rebindLastSelectBox() {
    $('#selectList:last').change(function(e) {          
                $(this).unbind('change');
        $('table').append("<tr id='selectWrapper'>" + selectRow + "</tr>");
                rebindLastSelectBox();
   });
};
```

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>JS Test</title>
    <script src="./js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="./js/application.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Title</td><td><input type="text" name="some_name" value="" id="some_name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='selectWrapper'> 
        <td>Items</td><td><select name="items[]" id="selectList" size="1">
            <option value="1">Item 1</option>
            <option value="2">Item 2</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

All suggestions gratefully recieved!

Adam

Comment: I'm honestly not really sure what's going on with your code. How can "#selectList:last" have any meaning whatsoever? How can you have a "last" id?

Comment: he is copying the row, so will have two id's which of course is not valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get you working just change the id's to classes on the tr and the select.
The js can be improved however lets get you working first.

```
<head>
    <title>JS Test</title>
    <script src="./js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="./js/application.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Title</td><td><input type="text" name="some_name" value="" id="some_name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='selectWrapper'>     
        <td>Items</td><td><select name="items[]" class="selectList" size="1">
                <option value="1">Item 1</option>
                <option value="2">Item 2</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>

var selectRow;
$(document).ready(function() {
    selectRow = $('tr.selectWrapper').html();
    rebindLastSelectBox();  
});

function rebindLastSelectBox() {
    $('select.selectList:last').change(function(e) {                  
        $(this).unbind('change');
        $('table').append("<tr class='selectWrapper'>" + selectRow + "</tr>");
        rebindLastSelectBox();
   });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on changing to classes rather that IDs. After changing my ids however I can see no dynamic updating of the page. I'd be interested to see how you'd improve the javascript too.
Cheers,
Adam